# C++ why is the reference lost?

Tags: c++, templates, reference, c++17

If I do:

```cpp
struct Foo {
  int a, b;
};

template<typename T>
void bar(T object) {}

void call(Foo& f) {
  bar(f);
}

int main() {
  Foo f{1, 2};
  call(f);
}
```

The function called is `bar<Foo>`, but why isn't it `bar<Foo&>`? Inside `call`, `f` is a `Foo&`, so the template deduction should call `bar<Foo&>`, no? If I wanted it to call `bar<Foo>`, I would have written `bar<Foo>(f)` explicitly, so why does it deduces the type `Foo` anyway?

Comment: Watch this awesome talk by Scott Meyers: https://youtu.be/wQxj20X-tIU

Comment: inside `call`, the expression `f` is an lvalue of type `Foo`. There are no expressions of reference type.   Also, template parameters are never deduced to reference type unless it is specifically a *forwarding reference*.